# suppressing WCF error

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

I have written a WCF service. The client is built up in Silverlight.

It works fine, but as soon as the internet connection is lost even for a second, my application throws an error in a message box "the remote server returned an error not found"

Also, it sometimes thorws WCF Request Timed Out exception. All these exceptions are displayed in a message box. I wanted to know if there is a way to suppress these exceptions, as-in I don't want a message box to be popped up everytime with these messages.

Please give me some leads. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your first issue. 
The second issue can be solved by two ways: 1.set up client side binding timeout to longer time in web.config 2.write code to set up binding timeout. The following example sets up BasicHttpBinding at code behind.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.ReceiveTimeout = System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:10:00");
binding.SendTimeout = System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:10:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to catch the Exception in the Catch block and there you can keep the process for the ideal state for some time.

After some time again try to access the remote services. This will how you can handle this.